# Unable to place my button to the specified side in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I was using tkinter in python 3.6 so that i could learn GUI programming. I tried to create a button. When I try to `pack` my button to `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` I am not getting the output whereas the `side=top` works for the frame command.please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
         from tkinter import *
         import tkinter as tk
         root = tk.Tk()
         topframe = Frame(root)
         topframe.pack()
         bottomframe = Frame(root)
         bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)
         button1 = Button(topframe, text="helo boys", fg="green")
         button1.pack()
         button2 = Button(topframe, text="how are you", fg="red")
         button2.pack(side=LEFT)
         button3 = Button(bottomframe, text="we are fine", fg="blue")
         button3.pack(side=RIGHT)
         root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `fill=X` to those `.pack(...)` for the two frames and then you will see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pack both buttons to the `tk.LEFT` of the `topframe`:

```
import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    topframe = tk.Frame(root)
    topframe.pack()

    bottomframe = tk.Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    button1 = tk.Button(topframe, text="hello boys", fg="green")
    button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    button2 = tk.Button(topframe, text="how are you", fg="red")
    button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    button3 = tk.Button(bottomframe, text="we are fine", fg="blue")
    button3.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    root.mainloop()
```

`button3.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)` has the same effect as `button3.pack()` because this element is the only widget in `bottomframe`

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    topframe = tk.Frame(root)
    topframe.pack()

    bottomframe = tk.Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    button1 = tk.Button(topframe, text="Hello boys", fg="green").place(x=140, y=380)
    button2 = tk.Button(topframe, text="How are you", fg="red").place(x=140, y=380)
  

    button3 = tk.Button(bottomframe, text="We are fine", fg="blue").place(x=140, y=380)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: An answer that is just code without an explanation isn't very useful. Could you describe what you did to solve the problem? Otherwise the reader has to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed.